# Foursquare check-in

Tags: android, foursquare

I am working in Android. I have done almost all the work which is required for Foursquare integration in an Android application.

Now I am trying to add check in functionality in this application.

This is my code in android for foursquare check-in :

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?venueId=4d6a73bafd7ea35d0c08b24a&shout=great....&broadcast=public&oauth_token=myauthtoken");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

Please tell me whether I am doing right or not? Actually I dont know that what is the procedure to add check in functionality for a venue through Foursquare in our android application.

Comment: You have asked 105 questions and you still didn't learn to [format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) them correctly so that code snippets are readable!

Comment: Sir Darin, I am working on this issue since the past 5 days but still haven't reached a solution. If you have the solution then I'll be really greatful because I am more worried about my application rather than my formatting skills

Comment: you should be very much worried about your formatting skills when asking on public forums.

Comment: Ok Darin..I'll keep that in mind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
HttpContext localContext;
private String ret;
HttpResponse response = null;
HttpPost httpPost = null;

public String sendPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> data, String contentType) {
    ret = null;

    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);

    httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    response = null;

    StringEntity tmp = null;

    httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.215 Safari/535.1");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5");

    if (contentType != null) {
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    } else {
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }

    try {
        tmp = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    }

    httpPost.setEntity(tmp);
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);


    if (response != null) {
        ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }


    return ret;
}
```

Try using this method to post your checkin url with an empty ArrayList and null contentType.

Comment: here what is the reference of localContext . Please help me...

Comment: i am getting the response like this:=={"meta":{"code":410,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"The Foursquare API no longer supports requests that do not pass in a version parameter. For more details see https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/overview\/versioning"},"response":{}}

Comment: I am getting the response like this======{"meta":{"code":410,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"The Foursquare API no longer supports requests that do not pass in a version parameter. For more details see https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/overview\/versioning"},"response":{}}

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem like this:-

```
    try {

                     HttpPost post = new 
   HttpPost("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?venueId="+mNearbyList.get(position).id+"&shout=great....&broadcast=public&oauth_token="mytoken");



                        HttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);
                    //    Log.v(TAG,"response from server "+EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity()));  
                          if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
                         {
                              Toast.makeText(PlacetoCheckin.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              String response = EntityUtils
                                .toString(rp.getEntity());
                        Log.v(TAG,
                                "response from server====="
                                        + response);
                          }
               }
               catch(Exception e){}
              }
            });
```

Comment: I am getting the response like this=={"meta":{"code":410,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"The Foursquare API no longer supports requests that do not pass in a version parameter. For more details see https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/overview\/versioning"},"response":{}}.  Please help me..In that what i did mistake?

Answer (score 0):

There is some old Android code on Google Code that was written by FourSquare for what appears to be an Android FourSquare app.  Maybe you can find some examples there.

Here is the link:  http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/source/browse/#hg